# Could you verify I calculate unbiased correlation?

Tags: r, time-series, pearson-r

I study correlations in a long natural timeseries of stock returns. Below is a code that uses dummy timeseries `x` for demonstration of algorithm.

My concern is as follows:

When I take `diff(x, lag = i)` where i > 1, the resulting timeseries is not i.i.d.: the values are long-memory correlated due to overlapping lagged values. Let's say `i = 600`, for example.

I decided to take a uniformly sparse sample of `x` with

```
rand_start <- runif(1, 1, 1000)

          sample_indexes <- seq(
               from = rand_start
               , to = (length(x_diffed) - rand_start - max_lag) %/% i * i
               , by = i
          )
```

in order to remove neighborhood correlations.

So I get `x_diff(1) = x(601) - x(1), x_diff(2) = x(1201) - x(601), ...`

The other variable I use to get auto-correlation coefficient is just shifted at `i steps.`

**Is doing this kind of sparse sampling a convenient practice in this case?**

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
library(data.table)

x <- cumsum(rnorm(1000000, 0, 1)) ### think of it as a raw stock price

pacf(diff(x))

cortest <- data.table()

max_lag <- 7200

max_iter <- 100

for(
     i in 1:max_lag
){

     x_diffed <- diff(x, lag = i)

     tests <- numeric()

     for(j in 1:max_iter)
     {

          rand_start <- runif(1, 1, 1000)

          sample_indexes <- seq(
               from = rand_start
               , to = (length(x_diffed) - rand_start - max_lag) %/% i * i
               , by = i
          )

          sample_indexes2 <- sample_indexes + i

          tests[length(tests) + 1] <-
               cor.test(
                    x_diffed[sample_indexes]
                    , x_diffed[sample_indexes2]
               )$estimate

     }

     cortest <- 
          rbind(cortest
                , data.table(
                     corr = tests
                     , lags = i
                    )
                )

     if(
          i%%10 == 0
     )
     {
          print(i)

          median_corr <- cortest[, list(median_corr = median(corr)), by = lags]

          boxplot(corr ~ lags
                  , data = cortest
                  , main = "Lagged correlation of Pearson"
                  , xlab = "Variable lag"
                  , ylab = "Pearson's R")
          lines(
               x = median_corr[, lags]
               , y = median_corr[, median_corr]
               , col = 'red'
               , lwd = 3
                )
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After studying results I conclude that approach is approximately right, but p-values associated with Pearson's R statistic grow rapidly, making so long analysis unnecessary.